# Share usb port for USB-C or Lightning

Tags: usb

Our car has both Android Auto and Carplay support, which is great. Problem is, wife has an iPhone (Lightning connector) and I have an Android phone with usb-c. The vehicle has only one usb port that can be used for AA or Carplay, so the only way to use both is to disconnect and swap cables.
What I would like to have, but seems like nobody invented, is a "smart" usb cable that splits into both usbc and lightning and automatically selects which one to use depending on which one is plugged in. Alternatively a manual switch on the cable could also work.
Does such a thing exist? Any other ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried a USB hub?

Answer (score 0):

You can buy a multi usb cable like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071WNQYV6).

Comment: Aren't those multi cables charge only? Also thought carplay won't work with a hub.

Comment: You’re right looks like hubs won’t work. I’ve updated the answer with a link to a cable with data which should work.

Comment: Thanks! The problem with that cable is I need to swap out the tips, effectively making it just slightly better than swapping out the cable.
I was hoping I could have both cables and just plug in either one.
Also, since the base of that cable is micro-usb, I end up with a fairly long and breakage-prone connector when using usbc / lightning.